# Start function after click on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, html

I have a div element and a function of timer, as below.

How to start the function after clicking the div ?

```
<div id="link"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var obj = document.getElementById('link');
    var timerFIG = 7;
    var timer = setInterval("startTimer()",1000);
    function startTimer() {
        if(timerFIG !== 1) {
            timerFIG--;
        } else {
            clearInterval(timer);
            obj.innerHTML = '<img src="/button.png" border="0" />';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I've updated my answer using only `javascript` try it now and let me know if its worked

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery

```
//dom ready handler
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $obj = $('#link');
    var timerFIG = 7;
    var timer;

    //click handler for the link
    $obj.click(function () {
        timer = setInterval(startTimer, 1000);
    })

    function startTimer() {
        if (timerFIG !== 1) {
            timerFIG--;
        } else {
            clearInterval(timer);
            $obj.html('<img src="/button.png" border="0" />');
        }
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/88LxN/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div id="link">7</div>

<input type="button" value="Start"  onclick="startcounting();"/>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var obj = document.getElementById('link');
    var timerFIG = 7;

    function startcounting()
    {
      var timer = setInterval(function(){

            if(timerFIG != 1) {
                         timerFIG--;
                         obj.innerHTML = timerFIG;
                  } else {
                   clearInterval(timer);
                   obj.innerHTML = '<img src="/button.png" border="0" />';
               }

         },1000);
    }
</script>
```